# Python 3 index is len(l) conditional evaluation error

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following merge sort code. When the line `if ib is len(b) or ...` is changed to use double equal `==`: `if ib == len(b) or ...`, the code does not raise an `IndexError` exception.

This is very unexpected because:

- len(b) is evaluated to a number and `is` is equivalent to `==` for integers. You can test it out: a python expression

  ```
   (1 is len([0]) )
  ```

  is evaluated to be `True`.
- the input to the function is `range(1500, -1, -1)`, and range objects are handled differently in python3. I was suspecting that since the input was handled as a range instance, the length evaluation might have been an instance instead of a integer primitive. This is again **strange** because

  ```
   1 is len(range(1))
  ```

  also gives you `True` as the result.

Is this a bug with the conditional evaluation in Python3?

Tom Caswell supplied this following useful express in our discussion, I'm copy pasting it here for your notice:

```
tt = [j is int(str(j)) for j in range(15000)]
```

only the first 256 items are `True`. The rest are `False` hahahaha.

---

The original script:

```
def merge_sort(arr):
    if len(arr) >= 2:
        s = int(len(arr)/2)
        a = merge_sort(arr[:s])
        b = merge_sort(arr[s:])
        ia = 0
        ib = 0
        new_arr = []
        while len(new_arr) < len(arr):
            try:
                if ib is len(b) or a[ia] <= b[ib]:
                    new_arr.append(a[ia])
                    ia += 1
                else:
                    new_arr.append(b[ib])
                    ib += 1
            except IndexError:
                print(len(a), len(b), ia, ib)
                raise IndexError
        return new_arr
    else:
        return arr

print(merge_sort(range(1500, -1, -1)))
```

Comment: Not an error, `is` test object identity, `==` tests value equality. When you use `==` in your conditional expression is short circuited so it never tries to index `b[ib]` so no IndexError.

Comment: @AChampion Thanks for the comment! I believe both these two versions are short-circuited. `is` should be the same for integer primitives. This is a bug for `is`.

Comment: Your test around `1==len([0])` vs `1 is len([0])` is flawed because Python caches integers with certain low values (see https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong). I don't believe you have found a Python bug - it appears to be behaving as documented.

Comment: @AlexTaylor Thanks! This link is very informative! I believe this is the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python does not guarantee that two integer instances with equal value are the same instance.  In the example below, the reason the first 256 comparisons return equal is because Python caches `-5` to `256` in `Long`. 
This behavior is described here: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong

example:

```
tt = [j is int(str(j)) for j in range(500)]
plt.plot(tt)
```

[image]

IIRC that any of them pass the `is` test is an implementation-specific  optimization detail.

Comment: Thanks Tom! with Alex's link to python caching of `Long` this answer is perfect. https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong

Answer (score 1):

`is` checks whether 2 arguments refer to the same *object*, `==` checks whether 2 arguments have the same *value*. You cannot assume they mean the same thing, they have different uses, and you'll get an error thrown if you attempt to use them interchangeably.

Comment: it is true and I'm aware, but I think the reason here is more subtle than this. 

I believe this has something to do with how the `range` object got handled, and it is a bug with python.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I accepted the other answer because of the test case it contains, and edited it with a link to python documentation.